# Disable foreign keys or pay attention to creation order

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, migration

I am currently developing a java application to migrate data of an Oracle database to an equivalent structured SQL Server database which I have migrated using liquibase. Now it is difficult to manage to migrate all foreign keys as well since many are dependent from others so I thought of two solutions:

1. Disable all foreign keys before the migration and afterwards enable them again
2. Take care of the foreign keys being created in the right order so that they will be created in the same way

The second way sounds for me more difficult but somehow safer while the first way sounds easier but could come out to be wrong or prone to errors. Actually I am not sure which one would even work. Which way would be better to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is: with liquibase you migrated the structure of tables from Oracle to SQLServer. To migrate data I would suggest unloading data from Oracle to flat files with e.g sqlplus and queries, load it to SQLServer with bcp. After data migration, I would create indexes and constraints. Starting with primary keys then foreign keys. In order to have unloaded data consistent, I would put Oracle in quiesce mode - allows only SYS commands. sqlplus and bcp are dedicated vendor's tools. Very fast and reliable.

Migrating with a custom-built application is pretty much the same - just replace sqlplus/bcp with your app. Data will load to SQLServer much faster without indexes nor constraints so first migrate data create indexes and constraints later.